# Internal server error when adding a user to a custom group programatically in Stripe recurring payment module controller

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

Hello everyone and thanks for taking the time to read my post.

I'm pretty new to Prestashop. I added the stripe recurring payment module from Prestashop addons. It works well.

But my goal is to add the user to a group according to the id of the product he is subscribing to in the `addStripeSubscription()` function of the module like advised kindly by the developer. I can't read the error since the module returns only that there has been a server error so I can't have more info on this.

Here's what I'm actually doing:

```
    $customer = new customer(6); //This is my customer id
    if ($id_product == 27) {
        // On ajoute l'user au groupe champion
        $new_id_group = 4; // This is an existing group's id
        if ($customer->id_default_group!=$new_id_group) {
            $customer->cleanGroups();
            $customer->addGroups([(int)$new_id_group]);
            $customer->id_default_group = (int)$new_id_group;
            $customer->update(); // It fails here
        }
    }

    // if ($id_product == 28) {
    //     // Groupe chevalier
    //     $new_id_group = 5;
    //      if ($customer->id_default_group!=$new_id_group) {
    //         $customer->cleanGroups();
    //         $customer->addGroups(array((int)$new_id_group));
    //         $customer->id_default_group = (int)$new_id_group;
    //         $customer->update();
    //     }
    // }
```

It fails at `$customer->update();` but only if `$customer->addGroups($new_id_group)` is not commented. So it has something to do with this `addGroups()` function. Even if I pass 3 (the default customer group in Prestashop) directly in parameter of `addGroups()` function it fails.

This is driving me crazy.

Why is that happening ? What am I missing ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Any info on error log?

Comment: @FranCerezo don't know if this is related, but found this in Logs: Exception on hook paymentOptions for module . Notice: Undefined index: currency_sign. But only 3 errors and I got like 20 internal server error when testing today....

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. The recurring stripe payment module or stripe module was passing to production mode while the other was not, and that randomly, that was what created the internal server error and I thought it was related to groups.

I also found a free module that permit to do something when something else happens so now I use this module to automatically add an user when he purchase a product that as a particular ID, and this customer is added to the group that I linked to the product. Crazy module.

Very dope module again for doing loooooots of things automatically.

https://store.getdatakick.com/en/modules/conseqs-free

Hope this will help some !